# filter not valid numeric string

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers

I have following problem :

I'm validating the filed values... I want to check if value is numeric format..

> allow formats : Integer, float

I tried already

```
var isDecimal_re = /^\s*(\+|-)?((\d+(\.\d+)?)|(\.\d+))\s*$/;
alert(String(value).search (isDecimal_re) != -1);
```

but it allows `01` as valid number
I want to allow just integers and float numbers

### validation rules

```
1.0 => true
0.1 => true
0 => true
19 => true
1. => true (because it is possible to continue correctly)
5. => same case here
```

how write regEx or some function to prevent 01 kind of Case ?

Comment: Is there any other solution ?

Comment: or `var is_valid = parseFloat(value) == value`;

Comment: 01 in this case isNan not working correctly

Comment: Why does it matter if the number start with zero, just remove the zero and let the user type leading and following zeros as they choose, it shouldn't generally  affect the outcome anyway?

Comment: Number(value) would be the good choice.